# PHP curly braces in database value

Tags: php, mysql

so I have an issue. We have some values in our DB stored like the following:

```
{yoyoyo}
```

This is great until we pull the value out of the DB using PHP. It appears to break PHP when trying to access the variable like so:

```
$result['curly'];
```

For some reason PHP is interpreting that as if its a variable.

Anyone know how to escape the result from the DB so PHP interprets it as a string and not a variable?

Thanks!

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem accessing a string like that. Where is the error occurring?

Comment: I dont think there would be any discrepancy. If that is the case with $ character then you have to take extra care of it

Comment: why this problem is not facing by me I added the same value in my databse and I got currect array      
            [CompanyName] => {yoyoyo}
            [City] => test
            [Country] => {yoyoyo}


http://nimb.ws/WzgC9L this is my OP image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, after further research it appears that it's pulling the string value out of the DB just fine. However, later on in our code we were doing other, lets just say, inefficient stuff. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use htmlentities - http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

This will convert all characters to html entities.  You can also in the future store things that don't need to be used as variables to html entities before putting them in the database to avoid this problem.

http://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html